# Loop through files in 1 folder and NOT any subfolders batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, directory

I'm trying to loop through all files of .properties extension, in a root folder:"C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\, but not any subfolders within that root folder, how can I achieve this result? Code below:

```
 FOR /R "C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\" %%G IN (*properties) DO Echo %%G
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the /R option of the FOR command.

Try just

```
 FOR %%G IN (C:\ExecutionSDKTest_10.2.2\*.properties) DO Echo %%G
```